# Parameters vs String interpolation

Tags: c#, sql

What is the advantage of using parameters over using string interpolation?

Is this

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Posts WHERE Author = @p0", userSuppliedAuthor;
```

any better than

```
$@SELECT * FROM dbo.Posts WHERE Author = {userSuppliedAuthor}";
```

?

Comment: Interpolation ==> SQL Injection. Don't do it. Check [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos anything other than SQL injection?

Comment: @cikatomo lots - date and number conversion problems, mangled non-English text. It's actually *easier* to use parameters with eg Dapper. `con.Query<Posts>("select  * from Posts where Author=@author",new {autthor=someAuthor});"`

Comment: ...unless you're using library methods that explicitly leverage interpolation for building parameterized commands (e.g. https://github.com/Drizin/InterpolatedSql/)

Comment: Or EF Core's `.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

String interpolation is just a syntax sugar for formatting string. It gives you no protection against SQL injection. You should use SQL parameters to provide values for your query.

Consider - what if `userSuppliedAuthor` equals to

```
'Bob' OR 1 = 1
```

Or even

```
'Bob'; DROP TABLE Users;
```

Further reading [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: or `"'Bob'; DROP TABLE  dbo.Posts;"`

Comment: @TimSchmelter yep, tried to add such sample, but editor does not allow to insert DROP users table into answer body :)

Comment: @farzin-kanzi Sanitizing keywords is the least of your problems. There are a whole host of things that can be injected to give your application inconsistent behavior (e.g. 'Bob' or author <> ''). Additionally, if you go the sanitization route, you also have to sanitize text (e.g. apostrophes, etc)

Comment: any other objection except sql injection?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to SQL injection issues mentioned by Sergey, you can have issues with totally valid strings that contain certain characters, like "'", "." and "@" characters that mean things to SQL and need to be handled. It's always best to parameterize queries to prevent these issues, not only with injection when going straight from user input, but even something as simple as an email address or a possessive in a title.