# EF Core 2.0 how to use SQL stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-core-migrations

I am new to EF Core 2.0 with stored procedure.

Can anyone help how to use stored procedure in my EF Core 2.0 code-first approach?

With my previous project, I had an `.edmx` model file, and I was using the context as below:

```
public IEnumerable<UserResult> GetUserResults(Entities context)
{
    if (context == null) return new List<UserResult>();
    return context.spGetUsers().Where(u => u.IsDeleted == false);
}
```

and the context is:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<UserResult> spGetUsers()
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<UserResult>("spGetUsers");
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the FromSQL method:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogs")
    .ToList();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: Many Thanks. So, after all migrations are executed, i just have to create the stored procedure in the database. is that right?

Comment: Yes, or you can create them during migrations using the Sql() method (edit the migration)

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry to ask you one more thing on the same line. Currently my 'UserResult' is not an enitty on the database. It is [NotMapped]. In that case how do i execute the query? as in your example context.Blogs, i dont have context.UserResults. Thank you

Comment: Read the docs, and you will see that this is currently not possible

Comment: If you are referring to use of Query Types this feature is now in EF Core 2.1:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types

Answer (score 8):

To save someone else an hour or so...

ErikEJ's answer works perfectly but I had some extra work to do first.

Following a reverse code first migration (to an existing database with stored procedures), I had a problem where the stored procedures on an existing database did not return the standard table (e.g. list of `Blog`), but a different class (e.g. list of `BlogTitleAndSummary`) which was not in the database (and therefore the migration).

This post stated that the return [must be an entity type](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx), which I was unsure of, but [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42501615/852806) of Eriks posts pointed me in the right direction.

To get this scenario working:

I created a class of 'BlogTitleAndSummary', marked one property as the `[key]`.

e.g.

```
public class BlogTitleAndSummary
{
    [Key]
    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string ShortSummary { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I added it as a DbSet on the Context e.g.

```
public partial class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext()
    {
    }

    public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    // Might be best to move these to another partial class, so they don't get removed in any updates.
    public virtual DbSet<BlogTitleAndSummary> BlogTitleAndSummary { get; set; }

    // Standard Tables
    public virtual DbSet<Blog> Blog { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This enabled me to use the following syntax for calling stored procedures:

NOTE: I have updated this following the comment below. Use the params in the FromSql method. Do not use string interpolation for such [sql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960481/parameters-vs-string-interpolation).

```
using (var ctx = new BloggingContext())
{
var dbResults = ctx.BlogTitleAndSummary.FromSql("EXEC dbo.get_bloggingSummary @UserId={0}", userId).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to make you and others aware that your specific example `string query = @"EXEC [dbo].[get_bloggingSummary]
        @User = N'" + userId + @"';` is not safe no matter how well written your stored procedure is, and you shouldn't ignore that warning. The query should be parameterized by either passing in the parameters separately `FromSql("exec dbo.get_bloggingSummary {0}", userId)`, or by using string interpolation `FromSql($"exec dbo.get_bloggingSummary {userId}")`, which EF Core will automatically parameterize for you.

Comment: @sgbj - Thank you. I have updted the example (and my own code!) following your comments. It does indeed remove the warning about sql injection attacks.