# Calling stored procedure from CRUD operation inside controller (ASP.NET Core MVC)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-core-mvc

This `CREATE` controller method inside ASP.NET Core MVC will take in `opportunityId` and `serialNum` as user inputs.

```
// POST: OrdersSerialNumbers/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]         
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("opportunityId,serialNum")] OrdersSerialNumbers ordersSerialNumbers)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(ordersSerialNumbers);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(ordersSerialNumbers);
}
```

I want to use these two inputs and pass those in this stored procedure below as a parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddOrdersSerialNumbers] 
     (@OpportunityId VARCHAR(18),
      @SERLTNUM VARCHAR(21)
     ) 
AS
```

How can I call the stored procedure in my create method to pass in the two user inputs and get a result list back instead of the number of rows getting affected?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/q/48211291/2030565

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF Core 2.0 how to use SQL stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211291/ef-core-2-0-how-to-use-sql-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo I made ,you could refer to and modify the code as per your needs

Create Stored Procedure AddAuthor , the parameters must match the fields in the table you want to add.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddAuthor]
    @Book nvarchar(20),
    @Length nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
Insert into Author(Book,Length)   
       Values (@Book,@Length) 
END
GO
```

Execute Stored Procedure using ExecuteSqlCommand() ,you could specify @p0 for the first parameter, @p1 for the second, and so on..

```
 _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC AddAuthor @p0, @p1", parameters: new[] { author.Book, author.Length });
```

Comment: ExecuteSqlCommand just returns back a number of rows getting affected. What if my stored procedure is a select statement and I want to get the result list back?

Comment: Yes ,Valid operations of ExecuteSqlCommand are INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. The method is not used for returning entities.But you could get the entity data via using `FromSql ` method to call the stored procedure which is a select statement ,please refer to : https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql#stored-procedures